# time validation using annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to enter date time as string inside textbox. Actually there are two input fields

- From time
- To time

Both should be in format like 00:00 so I can enter

From time `00:00`
To time `23:59`

how can validate user input in asp.net mvc viewmodel using annotations so I can restrict users input from `00:00` as min value and `23:59` as max value?

Comment: Where does "date" validation come in here? It sounds like you only have a time-of-day value, not a date. And why do you want to prevent midnight from being entered? That sounds like a bad validation rule to me - what if the thing you're talking about *does* start (or end) at midnight?

Comment: You're right, it should be in range of 00:00 to 23:59. edited.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom attribute that you can decorate your property with.

```
namespace JensB.Tools.CustomAttributes
{
    public class IsDateOk: ValidationAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            if (value == null) return false;
            if (value.GetType() != typeof(DateTime)) throw new InvalidOperationException("can only be used on DateTime properties.");
            bool isValid = // do validation here

            return isValid;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then decorate your property like this:

```
[IsDateOk(ErrorMessage="Dates must be .....")]
public property DateTime MyTime {get; set ;}
```

The nice part about doing this is that you basically dont need to code anything on the front end and just need to display the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor( x=> ....)` to make this work

Comment: The validation is done server side, but the error is shown on the client side. The message written in `ErrorMessage="Dates must be ....."` will be shown in the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor( x=> ....)` so the end user will see the error.

Comment: Yes, but only after a post-back to the server, not via JS directly on the client-side, like the built in validators do.

Comment: That is true, but I would never (ever) trust a javascript to clean user input. In the real world you would probably want to do this, and perhaps have a separate javascript code to make a "pretty" error right away without a submit.

Comment: Of course you should NOT trust on JS, but it is still an important fact the OP may not know, that this does not work with that solution as it is a usability drawback...

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression, you can validate your model, and client side validation also work with this
like

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(0[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] (am|pm|AM|PM)$", ErrorMessage = "Error message")]
public string FromTime {get;set;}
```